# Yarn package times out when using "docker-compose up"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I've been trying to run a development environment of [the following](https://github.com/joe-re/sql-language-server) SQL language server for VS Code. In the README, it says to use `docker-compose up` to initiate the docker container. However, every time I execute this command, I receive this error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz: ETIMEDOUT"
```

I did research on issues with fetching Yarn packages, and the most prominent solution involved increasing the maximum timeout to 100000, and I did so with the following command:

```
yarn add colors/-/colors-1.4.0.tgz --network-timeout 100000 -W
```

This executes successfully, but I still receive the exact same error when I run `docker-compose up`. Another solution I found included manually downloading the package, and including a new `COPY` statement in the dockerfile with the location details (ex: `COPY ./docker/colors-1.4.0.tar /opt/sql-language-server/docker`), but this did nothing.

Comment: timeout means network problems. Maybe it happens because of farewell rules or something like that...

Comment: @rzlvmp When I navigate to the page in the browser, I can download the package without any issue.